# How to fill a search box and get searched,result page using requests in python?

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests, python-3.4

I am new to web-scraping using python and i want to take input from command line ,fill it in the search box of the website and get the final result page without opening the browser.

Thankyou.

Comment: Please provide with the URL

Comment: https://mp3skull.la/

Comment: I could provide you with some sample code but I'm afraid you wouldn't understand. I think it's better for you to read about **XPath** and understand how mp3skull.la behaves (e.g. session passed through `fckh` variable)

Answer (score 0):

It is actually a lot simpler than you think. Using Google search as an example, let's say you want to search Google for 'foo bar'. So you navigate to Google's home page and search for 'foo bar' and it takes you to the url 'https://www.google.com/#q=foo+bar'.

So if you want this page and you want to use requests then all you need is

```
r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/#q=foo+bar')
```